# Daily Deal, About Us, FAQ, Contact Us, and Download link is not working?

Tags: magento-1.7

In my site, Daily Deal, About Us, FAQ, Contact Us, and Download link is not working.
  Earlier it was working but now when i am clicking on these links, it is not redirecting to that page.I think there will be some problem occured due to adding Aitoc modules in admin site and the problem is appearing only when the compilation is enabled.
I have made a static block in admin for toplinks having identifier 'top_menu_links'.i called that static block in header.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('top_menu_links')->toHtml() ?>
```

then also it is not working.

Anyone have any idea to solve this issue, then please help me out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the admin First

system >> configuration >> web

check the "Use Secure URLs in Frontend" yes or No

If Yes then go to CMS static Block, please check the  menu link is it static base url or not

if static then please replace the index.php and check it will work

And also check the base url is like

http://example.com
or 
http://www.example.com

Change your static URL it will work

or

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('example')->toHtml() ?>
```

Please check it will work

thank you